# How to Fetch Data From 2 Tables Using PHP based on Checkbox Selection

Tags: php, join, checkbox, mysqli

I have 2 Tables

- wll_customer
- document_checklist

Using following Query I can able to fetch only selected fields(Based on check box selection also i have provided 2 input fields to serch for particular college or student) from wll_customer Table.

```
$tmp = "SELECT ".implode(",", $sql_columns)." FROM wll_customer WHERE (customer_university = '$university_search' OR customer_name = '$name_search') AND customer_counselor ='".$_SESSION['user_name']."'";
```

I have two common fields in both table i.e **customer_id** Primary Key of wll_customer table, and **student_id** is Foreign key from document_checklist.

How can i Join both the tables?
I managed to fetch only the selected (checked by checkboxes) fields form **wll_customer** table  But, How about i want to fetch some more related fields from **document_checklist** by joining both the tables. 
 Any help may greatly appreciated.  Thank You!

Comment: Do you want to know the syntax of `JOIN`? Plese show us your table structures.

Comment: You said the word twice in your question.  [`JOIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html).

Comment: I will share with you tomorrow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I rectified the issue myself**

```
"SELECT ".implode(",", $sql_columns)." FROM wll_customer LEFT JOIN document_checklist ON wll_customer.customer_id=document_checklist.student_id WHERE (customer_university = '$university_search' OR customer_name = '$name_search') 
AND customer_counselor ='".$_SESSION['user_name']."'";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it if there is a common field for each of the tables.If you want to join table1 with table 2 having a field that can link on to each other i would be like this.

SELECT * FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON table1.id=table2.common_id WHERE ...

I dont know If I am understanding correctly your question, if not please send more information.

Comment: Instead of select *  from , i'm taking only the fields that are selected using check-boxes  SELECT ".implode(",", $sql_columns)."  FROM.<br /> and that 2 common field are not there in check boxes is it possible fetch based on WHERE condition

Comment: +1 For Your Hint Now i can able to display data from both the table where common field exist but, i want to display data from both the tables where common filed exist also if not exist i want display data from Table 1